# DRF: API root view doesn't list my APIs for some reasons

Tags: python, django, regex, routes, django-rest-framework

I have the following `urls.py` for an app named `service` where I register API endpoints:

```
from .views import AccessViewSet, CheckViewSet

app_name = "api"

router = DefaultRouter()

router.register(r"access/(?P<endpoint>.+)", AccessViewSet, basename="access")
router.register(r"check/(?P<endpoint>.+)", CheckViewSet, basename="check")


urlpatterns = [
    path("", include(router.urls)),
]
```

Below is my project's `urls.py` where I use it:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

import service.urls as service_urls

urlpatterns = [
    # ...
    path("service/", include('service.urls')),
]
```

The APIs themselves are functioning properly, but I am having trouble making them work with DRF's default API root view. The view is displaying an empty list of available endpoints. I'm not sure, but this issue may be related to the regular expressions I'm using when registering endpoints, such as `r"access/(?P<endpoint>.+)`. If this is indeed the problem, how can I resolve it?"

Answer (score 1):

`DefaultRouter` needs to run [`reverse(viewname)`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/reverse/#reverse) on your views to generate urls for the default view. It won't know about your dynamic parameter `endpoint` when it runs.

If it's acceptable to change your url structure to `{endpoint}/access/...` and `{endpoint}/check/...` you can:

```py
router.register(r"access", AccessViewSet, basename="access")
router.register(r"check", CheckViewSet, basename="check")


urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r"(?P<endpoint>.+)/", include(router.urls)),
]
```

After which, each `{endpoint}/` view should have a working default API view.

If you need to preserve your url structure, you'll have to manually generate a list of available routes like this:

```py
from collections import OrderedDict

from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.reverse import reverse

class ApiRoot(APIView):
    """My API root view"""

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        """List of available API endpoints"""

        api_methods = [
            "access-list",
            "check-list",
        ]

        endpoints = [
            "endpoint-a",
            "endpoint-b",
        ]

        routes = OrderedDict()
        for endpoint in endpoints:
            for method in api_methods:
                routes[endpoint + method] = reverse(
                    method, endpoint=endpoint, request=request, format=format
                )

        return Response(routes)
```

Notice the `endpoint=endpoint` in the reverse call.

If the code above doesn't help, please, expand your question with more details of what you're trying to archive in the first place. I have a feeling you might want to replace your viewsets with an `EndpointViewSet` with [custom ViewSet actions](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing) for `check` and `access`.

Finally, if you're looking for routes like `{endpoint_id}/access/{access_id}/...` and `{endpoint_id}/check/{check_id}/...` check out [drf-nested-routers](https://github.com/alanjds/drf-nested-routers) - a drop-in replacement for DRF's Routers that supports nesting.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I followed your first approach, but now when I access http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/ I get an error "Page not found". This is where API Root should be located (at least that's what I am striving for).
As for your other advice dealing with manually generating a list of avail. endpoints - I am using a regex placeholder for `endpoint` parameter, how do I know in advance all the possible `endpoints` then?

Comment: @varnie there are infinitely many strings that satisfy the regexp, so there is no knowing "all the possible" values in advance. If you expand your question with more info on what you're trying to build and what this parameter means, then maybe I can help you further, but as it's written right now, there is just not enough information in your question

Comment: I've 2 APIs, "/api/x/y/z/check" and "/api/x/y/z/access", where "/x/y/z" part denotes a url path of some 3rd party API I work with. Some valid "check" urls, to name a few, is: "/api/some/specific/3rdparty/endpoint/Im/interested/at/check". I hope you get an idea. So, basically speaking, my 2 APIs interact with the 3rd party APIs, the 1st API "checks" something using the 3rd party API, while the last one "accesses" it. And that's all. I am comfortable with the way these 2 APIs are defined. All I want is to make them  somehow accessible/visible through the API Root view page.

Comment: @ignato please correct me if I got it right: DRF API root view cannot "display" API urls which include dynamic parts. Thank you.

Comment: You got it right. It generates URLs using `reverse`, and `reverse` needs *values* for the dynamic parts (see my ApiRoot example).

As for the APIs, why not `/api/check/some/specific/3rdparty/endpoint/Im/interested/at/` and `/api/access/some...`? It seems that it would make your life easier

Comment: I would even pass it as a `?param=`

Comment: @varnie Oh, I'm sorry. Your original example indeed had it in that form. Right, it makes more sense now. So yea, I would just remove the `(?P<endpoint>.+)` from the `router.register` and pass it through the `request.query_params`

Comment: I got another Idea, what if you duplicate the registration with and without optional param:

```
router.register(r"access", AccessViewSet, basename="access")
router.register(r"access/(?P<endpoint>.+)", AccessViewSet, basename="access")
router.register(r"check", CheckViewSet, basename="check")
router.register(r"check/(?P<endpoint>.+)", CheckViewSet, basename="check")
```

Can you test that? I think it might complain about duplicated basenames, give it some random values if it does

Comment: Comments don't support multiline code. I hope you can read that

Comment: You want links to plain `access/` and `check/` on your default root view. Did I get that right?